# Put HTML Code to input field

Tags: javascript, php

I have this row that gives me an error because the value contains HTML Code.

```
document.getElementById(\'longstory\').value = \''.$row['longstory'].'\';
```

Is there any easy way to like encode it during passing and then when showing it in my value

```
<textarea class="form-control" id="longstory" name="longstory" placeholder="Longstory"></textarea><br />
```

to get it show as HTML for the user in the end?

Comment: The error is likely due to your broken quotes. If you give us a jsfiddle or just a small (less than 20 lines) bit of code that we can use to reproduce your error, we can probably help you better.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
echo "document.getElementById('longstory').value = " . json_encode(html_entity_decode($row['longstory'])) . ";";
```

`html_entity_decode()` will interpret HTML entity codes in the value, converting them into normal PHP characters. Then the output of `json_encode()` will be Javascript syntax for the value.

The problem isn't that it contains HTML, the problem is that it contains characters that aren't permitted in a Javascript string, such as unescaped quotes and literal newlines. `json_encode` encodes everything properly.

Comment: Is `json_encode` a standard javascript function? I wasn't aware of it. There are others that have become standard however. And libraries you can use for older browsers.

Comment: It's a standard PHP function.

Comment: He's clearly generating Javascript in his PHP script, that's what `$row['longstory']` is

Comment: Oh, I see. He must have just added the php tag.

Comment: I added the php tag when I figured out what he was doing.

Comment: It fixed that problem but the problem comes if `$row['longstory']` contains "'", how do I get past that? I can't change it to " because then that becomes a problem

Comment: Please edit your comment, and put backticks around the HTML stuff, because otherwise SO interprets it.

Comment: I think I know what you were asking, see the updated answer that uses `html_entity_decode` as well.

Comment: I can't read your comment, you forgot to put the special codes in backticks again.

Comment: @Barmar `html_entity_decode` did not change the state. It looks better indeed when looking in the textfield but I can not load up the ones containing an '

Answer (score 0):

Try use the htmlspecialchars and addslashes functions before passin to the js.

```
document.getElementById(\'longstory\').value = \''.addslashes($row['longstory']).'\';
```

Comment: htmlspecialchars is for HTML, not Javascript.

Comment: "value contains HTML Code..." Isn't that what OP wants, to encode HTML?

Comment: He's putting HTML code into a Javascript string, he's not putting it directly into HTML itself.

Comment: Ok, then only addslashes.